# Can we generate enough electricity to light up street lights by means of a dynamo being rotated by car wheels?

Tags: energy

I often wonder if we can place an efficient dynamo underground on a fast moving highway (where traffic flow rarely stops). The dynamo is mechanically rotated and generate electricity to lightup the street lights in this way.

Is it possible? What challenges would one be facing for such an idea or design?

Comment: How exactly is the dynamo rotated?

Comment: My 2 cents - First law of thermodynamics, energy cannot be created or destroyed.  Lighting the street lights will make the cars less efficient.  Cars will burn more gas to get to their destination and emisssions increase.  The conversion of energy will likely be very lossy requiring more fuel than if the grid were run off a gas powered generator.

Comment: It's not clear at all how this dynamo is supposed to be "rotated by the car wheels", but this makes little sense.  Even ignoring the expense of installing and maintaining the infrastructure, how can this possibly be more effecient that the power stations that produce electricity that street lights currently run from?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No traffic lights like small application could power in this way. But they use pizo electric energy harvesters, not electromagnetic dinamos. Energy harvesting is a large topic.

Comment: http://www.eetimes.com/electrical-engineers/education-training/courses/4370021/Fundamentals-of-Energy-Harvesting

Comment: How about having vehicles drive through a through a large coil to which a permanent magnetic field is applied? The vehicles will disturb the magnetic field, inducing a voltage in the coil. Some cars could even be permanently magnetized for a greater effect. :) Or, or! The turbulence generated by vehicles could spin hundreds of little turbines ...

Comment: I'd rather you worked on a scheme to get the street lights or the road to power my electric car :)

Comment: @gbarry That's not a bad idea either!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Most likely yes.

But:

> What challenges would one be facing for such an idea or design?

These are what I foresee as the biggest hurdles you'd have to overcome.

**Hurdle 1:** The laws of thermodynamics, in particular the first and second law. The first law of thermodynamics states that energy cannot be created or destroyed. There's a caveat here in that energy can be converted to and from mass using Einstein's famous equation, but there aren't any current automotive applications of Einstein's equation so we may as well assume energy and mass aren't converted to each other.

So whatever energy it takes to run the lights will have to be put in by any vehicles driving on our fictional energy converter. This wouldn't be a problem except for the second law of thermodynamics which states that the entropy of the universe is at best not increasing. This leads to the concept of efficiency. Not all the energy of the gasoline your car burns goes towards "useful" work. Most of it is lost as heat. In fact so much heat is created by your engine that engines have cooling systems designed just to keep it from melting itself. Common gasoline engines have typical efficiencies of around 35%. This is before any efficiency losses created by wind resistance or efficiency losses of converting the car's motion through the converter to the street lights. Typical power plants which operate in a different fashion reach efficiencies of 50% or higher. This means we would end up wasting a lot more energy by trying to power lights off of cars instead of off the grid. Note that this hurdle applies to many different kinds of energy harvesting methods, not just

**Hurdle #2:** The way automobiles work. Cars drive by transmitting power/torque to their wheels, getting them to spin. The wheel then spins and hopefully doesn't have significant slippage with respect to the ground, transmitting a friction force which moves your car forward. We say your car moves forward but there's no reason why we can't say the ground is moving backwards. If the ground is fixed from point A (source) to point B (destination) it really doesn't matter because either point B is getting closer to us or we're getting closer to point B.

However, if the ground is rotating like a giant treadmill, the wheels can be spinning and we'd be moving with respect to a point on the treadmill, but the same reference point will also be moving away from point B. At best the car is moving faster towards point B than the reference point on the treadmill is moving away from it, at worst the reference point is moving faster away than we're moving towards it. Either way we're straining the engine more and likely arriving at our destination later, if at all.

**Hurdle #3:** Reliability. A giant spinning dynamo is most likely not going to be reliable. This is because the system is being exposed weather, constant pounding of traffic, etc. The system would also be new and complex, the two worst enemies of reliability. Power plants and the grid used to transmit electricity are also quite complex, but these have had decades of refinement and testing to produce highly reliable systems.

**Hurdle #4:** Cost. The electrical grid and power plants aren't there just to power street lights. They power our homes and businesses, too. They can also use a variety of energy sources such as wind, solar, coal, natural gas, nuclear, hydroelectric, etc. Many of these energy sources are significantly cheaper or easier/cheaper to harvest in large scale. In many cases these facilities already exist. In the other cases I would argue that powering street lights are the least of your worries.

**Conclusion:** I'm sure it's possible someone could design a system to do what you described, but it would almost certainly be highly impractical, unreliable, and expensive.